# Right click and left click tab open

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bigcommerce

I am working on a Big Commerce Cms.I was wondering is there any way when the visitor click on the header logo it go to home page and when it click on the same header logo with right mouse click  it goes to a alternative page,Thanks in advance

Comment: Bad Idea. You forget Mac has no right click.

Comment: My mac has a right click

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="/">
<img src="logo.png" onContextMenu="window.location='https://bing.com'"/>
</a>
```

The above code has the logo image in between the A tag which points to your home page, while the right click will take you to the link which you mention inside it...Hope it helps

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qct8v2qh/)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve what you're asking. One way is to use onClick to set the browsers location upon click, and use onContextMenu to set the browsers location on right click (AKA context menu). 
In the example below, note that in addition to setting the browsers location, we return "false" in the onContextMenu which prevents the actual "right click" menu from showing up in the browser.

```
 <div onClick="window.location='https://google.com'"  onContextMenu="window.location='https://bing.com'; return false">
 Logo Here
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I have added this code but it shows a menu tab on right click